# How to get the MAX(SUM of values) to find the category with the biggest total? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. One is Transactions and the other is Tickets. In Tickets I have the Ticket_Number,the name of the Category(Theater,Cinema,Concert), the Price of the Ticket. In Transactions I also have the Ticket_Number. What i want to do is to Get a SUM of money for each Category, and then with that data I want to Select the Category with the most money.

I already managed to get the SUM for each category but I am stuck here

```
SELECT category, SUM (Tickets.Price) AS Price  
FROM Tickets,Transactions  
WHERE Tickets.ticket_num=Transactions.ticket_num  
GROUP BY Category  
ORDER BY Price DESC;
```

I know i can add LIMIT 1 but I know it's not correct because 2 or more values can be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a sequence based on the sum of the price.  Then, restrict to only the matching aggregated row with the highest total price.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT category, SUM(t1.Price) AS Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(t1.Price) DESC) rn  
    FROM Tickets t1
    INNER JOIN Transactions t2
        ON t1.ticket_num = t2.ticket_num  
    GROUP BY Category
)

SELECT category, Price
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Price DESC;
```

Note that if you want to capture all categories tied for the highest price, should a tie occur, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` in the above CTE with `RANK`, keeping everything else the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a window function `DENSE_RANK()` which will handle ties properly.

`RANK()` will also work for your case, but if you would like to extend it to get `TOP N` places with ties (where `N > 1`), dense rank is the way to go.

```
SELECT Category, Price
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Category, 
    SUM(ti.Price) AS Price, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(ti.Price) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM Tickets ti
  INNER JOIN Transactions tr ON
    ti.ticket_num = tr.ticket_num  
  GROUP BY Category
  ) t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

I've also replaced the old style and not recommended joining of tables as comma separated list in `FROM` clause to a proper `INNER JOIN` clause and assigned aliases to tables.

Comment: You _don't_ need `DENSE_RANK` here, `RANK` will do just fine (and should perform slightly better as well).

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for you comment. I actually stated this in my answer, didn't I? Posted an extendable solution, so that the OP will know when the need comes that `RANK` won't be the way to go and there won't be any surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()` to rank the sums of the prices, more expensive first.

```
SELECT category,
       price
       FROM (SELECT category,
                    sum(tickets.price) price,
                    rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(tickets.price) DESC) r
                    FROM tickets
                         INNER JOIN transactions  
                                    ON transactions.ticket_num = tickets.ticket_num
                    GROUP BY category) x
       WHERE r = 1;
```

I also took the liberty to rewrite your join from the ancient comma style to a modern, clearer version.